# ANN Variable Correlation

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, correlation

I am using an ANN for predicting high value customers based on their first 0, 5, 10 days.

I've made 3 variables: `PurchasesOnDay0`, `PurchasesOnDay0to5`, `PurchasesOnDay0to10`.

`PurchasesOnDay0to5` will include `PurchasesOnDay0` and `PurchasesOnDay0to10` will include `PurchasesOnDay0to10` and `PurchasesOnDay0to5`.

My question is, will the ANN pick up the correlation and adjust accordingly or will this be a problem when creating my model?

Answer (score 1):

Generically speaking a neural network can automatically learn the needed feature transformation for a model to perform well.  What tends to matter more is how the features relate to your output.

If you're ever bored, you can run your original matrix, a transformed matrix that has been de-correlated via a principle axis transformation, and the original matrix combined with correlation information.  I suspect performance using the same architecture will be relatively similar.